# Uniswap V2 Router, Factory on Sepolia Test Network

Tags: solidity, uniswap, uniswapv2

Is it possible to use a Uniswap V2 router in Sepolia? what is the contract address of a router? What I got is only for the Goerli test network, and it is already an obsolete network, and you have to pay to get the tokens which is ridiculous.

```
//Goerli-TestNetwork UniswapRouter
uniswapRouterAddress = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"
```

Comment: You can find the addresses here: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot use it because
if we want to test our smart contract by deploying on Goerli then we use uniswap V2 Router address 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D but as we know Goerli faucet requires a minimum mainnet balance of 0.001 ETH on the wallet address being used.

if you want to use Sepolia then you need to deploy uniswap on the Sepolia network and then use it simply.

in case you don't want to deploy your own uniswap then you can simply use this particular address which is deployed on Sepolia Network and it works

0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008

Comment: thank you it worked perfectly